# create web service config file in access 2016 vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, web-config

I don't have any code yet as I don't know where to start! I see on the web that I'd need to select
on the Access toolbar external data  >>  more >> data services. Then it asks to point to a xml config file. Which I don't have and would need to create. I have the connection string from a VB.net application.

```
sWIPConnString As String = "SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=fake3465-vip.ent.agt.bb.ca)(PORT=41521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=fictitious_service_name)));uid=APP_getinfo;pwd=thispassword;"
```

I'd have to convert that to an xml version. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank in advance
Pete

Comment: Question appears to be 2-part: 1) figuring out correct structure for XML config file and 2) use VBA to build. However, why would you need VBA to build XML? Once you figure out correct XML, just use text editor to create a save file.

Comment: Does this help: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/link-to-a-data-service-5ce2738f-bf36-4490-a015-d1745d102bb8, states "You must already have the Data Service connection file, which is supplied by the Data Service provider".

Answer (score 0):

But those data services are not just any old plane jane web site. They are web sites that have installed, setup, and the developers of those web  sites setup that data service connection. And these custom connections are NOT general web sites, and they are not general web services that many sites have. And they are not a web API written around say SOAP or some REST standard.

So unless that web site decided to adopt this Microsoft specific means and method to expose data, then you not be able to use this feature to simple connect to any old web site out of the blue.  If you have a existing web site that exposes some web services? Then you have to use MSXML and consume that web data  yourself. That option in Access is not some general purpose setting or feature that allows connection to any old web site - only ones that have created that web service written to the business connection options that Microsoft created.

It not clear if you planning to create some web services on the target web site (that would assume you're the developer of that web site), or you trying to consume existing web services that the given site exposes. Even in this 2nd case, those exposed web services or even REST calls has ZERO to do with the feature in Access.

so that feature is of only use for connecting to web sites that offer specific created connection based on that standard from Microsoft - it not a general web service consuming feature built into access and you can't use that feature as such.

How to make a web service call from Access? Well, it has ZERO to do with that feature. Here is a MSXML exmaple:

[How to use XML web services in Access2007 which are built on Visual studio (2008/2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719898/how-to-use-xml-web-services-in-access2007-which-are-built-on-visual-studio-2008)

Comment: I can already connect to the web service using vb.net as a test platform. As it is now everything else is done in using Access as the front end. I don`t want to have to use 2 separate applications and would rather do everything in Access. Its the connection to the web service via Access VBA that I haven`t got a clue how to do. I`ll check the web service link you provided. We were supposed to convert the Access applications to a better platfom but its on hold for now!

Comment: Well as I stated, those special data connections in Access have ZERO to do with consuming a general web service and API that you are consuming like you are in .net. However, I all the time write such web service calls code in vb.net, and then simple call that vb.net code from Access - I find that's the most easy way to do this. So, take the vb.net and create a class - mark that class as a exposed class and you can then use createobject in Access/VBA and simply use your same vb.net code anyway.

Comment: There are lots of examples on how to consume your .net objects from Access/VBA. Here is one such post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54963628/vb-net-class-with-com-interop-missing-most-properties-when-used-from-vba-acces/54964476#54964476

Comment: Sorry to have taken so long , my boss sidetracked me to another task. I`ll look into it shortly!